# JS regex which allows lowercase letters and underscore (in between )

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I need to create a JS regext which only allow small letter and underscore (not in first or last ) .

> eg . abc_xyz or abcc or abc____xyc___sss

I am trying something like

```
/^[a-z]+$/
```

but not understand how to manage underscore

Comment: Maybe `/^[a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*$/`?

Comment: Is the number of letters before and after the underscore always three?

Comment: @AxelIngadi No, only small letters and underscore is allowed but underscore can't be first or last

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
/^[a-z]+(?:_+[a-z]+)*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AuWxVu/1/).  If there can be only 1 `_` between letters, replace `_+` with `_` (remove `+` after `_`).

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z]+` - 1+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `(?:_+[a-z]+)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `_+` - 1+ `_` chars
  - `[a-z]+` - 1+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[a-z]+_*[a-z]+$/.test('abc_xyz')
true
/^[a-z]+_*[a-z]+$/.test('_abc_xyz')
false
/^[a-z]+_*[a-z]+$/.test('abc_xyz_')
false
/^[a-z]+_*[a-z]+$/.test('abc____xyz')
true
/^[a-z]+_*[a-z]+$/.test('abcxyz')
true
```

This pattern doesn't allow an underscore at the start or end.

Comment: /^[a-z]+_[a-z]+$/.test('abcxyz') this should be pass but it fails same with abc____xyz

Comment: To allow for none or more underscores just add a * after the underscore. /^[a-z]+_*[a-z]+$/.test('abc____xyz')
true
/^[a-z]+_*[a-z]+$/.test('abcxyz')
true